# Band math with calc and / or overlay returning single-valued images

Tags: r, overlay, calc

When I try to run band math the result is always an image of a color and the values min and max very different from the one predicted.
I did not find any question here that showed this problem.
I worked out this way

```
r.stack <- stack("path to raster file"))
```

I use resampling instead of crop to cut out the white edges that were in the original images

```
prj <- "+proj=utm +zone=23 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m"
r <- raster(res=11.47, ext=extent(c(301496,  323919, 9888968, 9913982)), crs=prj, vals=NA
r.stack <- resample(r.stack, r)
```

After that the images have this configuration:

```
> class       : RasterBrick 
> dimensions  : 2181, 1955, 4263855, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
> resolution  : 11.47, 11.47  (x, y)
> extent      : 301496, 323919.8, 9888966, 9913982  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=23 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
>data source : in memory
>names       : l.1, l.2, l.3, l.4
>min values  :       -36.12217,           -45.12768,   -46.30455,                       -35.26328 
>max values  :      10.567671,         4.050200,         3.878345,                       11.613799
```

and than use the function below for calc

```
f <- function(x){
      (x[[2]])/(x[[1]])
}

s <- r.stack[[c(1,2)]]
r2 <- calc(s, f)
```

and I also run overlay whit the fun

```
f <- function(x,y){
     y/x
}
r2 <- overlay(r.stack[[1]], r.stack[[2]], fun= f)
```

Any of the methods result in a  [image of one value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SukMR.png)

Am I missing some steps?

Comment: `I use resampling instead of crop to cut out the white edges`. That is generally a bad idea as it degrades your data. Use `crop` or `trim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with some example data (without that it is hard to answer questions). I have simplified one function, a bit, but the results are the same.

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
b <- b/10 + 1

f <- function(x){ x[2]/ x[1] }
s <- b[[c(1,2)]]
r1 <- calc(s, f)

f <- function(x,y){ y / x }
r2 <- overlay(b[[1]], b[[2]], fun= f)
```

Or simply

```
r3 <- b[[2]] / b[[1]]   
r3
#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 7777  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : in memory
#names       : layer 
#values      : 0.7692308, 1.7  (min, max)
```

`r1` and `r2` are the same.

The reason that you get a "single color" is because most values are near 1, but there are a few big outliers; probably because of a division by a number between -1 and 1? This might illustrate it:

```
q <- quantile(r3, c(0.1, 0.9))
d <- clamp(r3, q[1], q[2])
plot(d)
```

And look at the extremes

```
i <- which.max(r3)
b[i][,2:1]
```